# How do i differentiate between two widgets on the same event

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have some input boxes which contain an text for the user to know what is required to enter. This text should disappear when the user clicks on it. How do i know which box the user clicked?

```
class window():
    def handleEvent(self,event):
        self.text.set("")
    def handleEvent2(self,event):
        a = self.efeld.get()
        print(a)
    def page0(self):
        self.text = tk.StringVar(None)
        self.text.set("Enter text here")
        self.efeld = ttk.Entry(fenster, textvariable=self.text)
        self.efeld.place(x=5, y=20)
        self.efeld.bind("<Button-1>",self.handleEvent)
        self.efeld.bind("<Return>",self.handleEvent2)
        self.text2 = tk.StringVar(None)
        self.text2.set("Enter text 2 here")
        self.efeld2 = ttk.Entry(fenster, textvariable=self.text2)
        self.efeld2.place(x=5, y=50)
        self.efeld2.bind("<Button-1>",self.handleEvent)
        self.efeld2.bind("<Return>",self.handleEvent2)
fenster = tk.Tk()
fenster.title("Test")
fenster.geometry("500x350")
fenster.resizable(False,False)
window().page0()
fenster.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `event.widget` attribute to get a reference to the widget that triggered the event.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `widget` attribute of the `event` object. It is a reference to the widget that got the event.

```
def handleEvent2(self,event):
    a = event.widget.get()
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using tkinker,
`event.widget` will contain what you want.

Sorry for short reply, navigating from mobile.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).